# OWA email body in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, outlook, outlook-web-app

Can I get OWA's (https://outlook.office.com/owa) selected email body into JavaScript via chrome extension? I have requirement to create Chrome Extension which copy email body into clip board. 
 
I have created Chrome Extension which copy any text into clipboard but can't get email body.

Comment: is there any way, I can get email body text or html of it ? In view source it shows different text but if I use firebug (or inspect element) it shows its HTML code.